# Load Bootstrap modal if click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap modal in my page and it has many different videos. So the page loads very slowly when it is first loaded.

HTML:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="dialogTestDialog{{$index}}"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="executionOptionLabel"
    aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="">
        <div class="close-video" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <video width="840" id="video">
          <source src="{{box.video}}" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
          <div class="controls">
            <button class="play"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <button class="pause"><i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close-btn-bottom"><i class="fa fa-stop" aria-hidden="true"></i></i></button>
            <button class="skip"><i class="fa fa-backward" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <!-- <button onclick="skip(10);"><i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> -->

            <!-- <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close-btn-bottom"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></i></button> -->
          </div>
...
```

What can I do to solve this problem? How can I load modal content after DOM? Thanks.

Comment: how about AJAX?

Comment: Use Ajax to populate your modals as requested.  This way the content is only loaded when the user requests it.

Comment: Since this is tagged angular use angular template and pass data to it from controller based on user interaction. Goes back to a prior question you asked where suggested you get rid of `bootstrap.js` and use `angular-ui-bootstrap`

Comment: Use external view template which will be loaded only with `$uibModal.open()`